# Angular2 nested module routing with same routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm facing a common problem in a backend app. 
I got several ressources which can be viewed by consulting this kind of routes:

- reports/view/:id
- campains/view/:id
- suts/view/:id
- certifications/view/:id

Note that the route ends with the same part : /view/:id.

My app modules are :

App.module 
  |-MainLayoutModule
    |- ReportModule
    |- CampaignModule
    |- SutModule
    |- ...

Each module (except mainlayoutModule) defines it's own routing.

App.routing

```
         {
            path:'certification',
            loadChildren: './+certification/certification.module#CertificationModule',
            canActivate:[AuthGuard]
        },
        {
            path:'reports',
            loadChildren: './+report/report.module#ReportModule'
            canActivate:[AuthGuard],
        },

         {
            path:'suts',
            loadChildren: './+sut/sut.module#SutModule',
            canActivate:[AuthGuard]
        },
        {
            path:'campaigns',
            loadChildren: './+campaign/campaign.module#CampaignModule',
            canActivate:[AuthGuard]
        },...
```

Report.routing

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReportDetailsComponent } from "./ReportDetails/report-details.component";
import { ReportDetailsResolver } from "./ReportDetails/report-details.resolver";
import { ReportListComponent } from "./ReportsList/report-list.component";

export const reportRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'list'
},
{
    path: 'view/:id',
    component: ReportDetailsComponent,
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Report detail'
    },
    resolve: {
        report: ReportDetailsResolver
    },
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'list',
    component: ReportListComponent,
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Reports Lists'
    },
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
];

export const reportRouting = RouterModule.forChild(reportRoutes);
```

Campaign.routing

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CampaignDetailsComponent } from './campaignDetails/campaign-details.component'
import { CampaignDetailsResolver } from './campaignDetails/campaign-details.resolver'
 import { CampaignListsComponent } from './campaignList/campaign-list.component'

export const campaignRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'view/:id',
    component: CampaignDetailsComponent,
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Campaign detail'
    },
    resolve: {
        campaign: CampaignDetailsResolver
    },
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'lists',
    component: CampaignListsComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
];

export const campaignRouting = RouterModule.forChild(campaignRoutes);
```

The campaign module needs to use directive from the report Component, here is it's code :

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
  CommonModule,
  campaignRouting,
  ReportModule
],
declarations: [CampaignDetailsComponent,CampaignListsComponent],
providers:[CampaignDetailsResolver]
})
export default class CampaignModule { }
```

Here is the problem : when i go to the route "/campaigns/view/:id" the router outlets  loads content from the report component module and not from the campaign component...

A stupid solution would be to have unique route in each module (like /view  Report/:id, /viewCampaign/:id... ) but i think i'm missing something in my app routing configuration....

Any idea on how to solve this kind of problem?
Thanks, 
Olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution here could be to change the way that you create your app hierarchy.

By using a "root" component for each module (report, campaign and stut), you could define "children" routes.

Here is an example from the ["Routing and Navigation"](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#a-crisis-center-with-child-routes) Guide :

```
const crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisListComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: CrisisDetailComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(crisisCenterRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class CrisisCenterRoutingModule { }
```

Also, i would recommend to follow a "Routing Module" way, like the one presented on the [same guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#refactor-routing-into-a-module) :

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HeroListComponent }    from './hero-list.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
const heroesRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'heroes',  component: HeroListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(heroesRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class HeroRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: this is it! thanks ! just used children routes! And it worked

Comment: For information i needed to refactor my modules with root components and RoutingModules too!